# Fastest way to calculate all routes in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, vector, traversal

I am looking for the most effective way to generate all routes between nodes inside a vector. Imagine the following (pseudo-)code:

```
vector<vector<Node>> step(vector<Node> list, Node nextStep)
{
    // 1. Erase current Node to avoid an infinite loop
    for(vector<Node>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it) == nextStep)
        {
              list.erase(e);
              break;
        }
    }

    // 2. Dig deeper into the list if more elements are available

    vector<vector<Node>> returnVector;
    if(list.size() > 0)
    {
        for(vector<Node>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(/* (*it) meets certain conditions*/)
            {
                vector<vector<Node>> tmp = step(list, (*it)); // Here the function calls itself



                for(vector<vector<Node>>::iterator n = tmp.begin(); n != tmp.end(); ++n)
                {
                    // 3. Insert "nextStep" at the beginning of the new path

                    (*n).insert((*n).begin(), nextStep);

                    // 4. Add new path to returnVector

                    returnVector.push_back((*n));
                }

                if(/* "nextStep" meets certain conditions */)
                {
                    // 5. Add "nextStep" as Node aswell

                    returnVector.push_back(std::vector<Node>{nextStep});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnVector;
}

    /*****
      .
      .
      .
      .
    */

void run()
{
    vector<Node> v(100, Node());

    for(auto n : v)
    {
        step(v, n);
    }

}
```

This function calculates all routes in a vector recursively. I have already tested it and it works quite well - as long as the count of elements inside the vector does not get too big.

I am very new to this area of programming (recursion and functions where performance actually really matters). As I have already written above I am looking for a more effective way to do the same task. The size of the vector can get quite big and the perfomance suffers drastically, blowing up CPU and RAM usage which is probably because of the recursion.

I know that there can be very many combinations, but maybe there are already better algorithms for this task.

Comment: look at [boost::graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) for some suggestions of algorithms solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: There is nothing in recursion _per se_ that forces extra memory consumption. The problem is that your recursive call takes the list by value, so it is actually doing a deep copy of the object. You should really try to pass by reference.

Comment: And for these kinds of algorithms, using `std::vector::reserve()` even if you don't know the exact future size, can drastically improve performance.

Comment: Are you asking for pointers to routing algo such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm ?

Comment: @rodrigo I had the same thought about the deep copy of the list but how could I pass it as reference when each instance of step () modifies it? And Thank you for telling me about reserve ()!

Comment: @Soren I heard about Dijkstras Algo. but I dont think it applies in my case as I search for all routes, not the shortest.

Comment: @Bobface Well, you do the changes, then you undo them. If it is worth it or not... you will have to measure it.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow, maybe it helps